# antmacher configuration is not working in spring 6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I started writing web security in my application without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, I have used springboot3 internally which uses spring 6 with this set up I am getting errors like Cannot resolve method 'antMatchers' in 'ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry'  from the below code

```
.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic()
```

**Complete method**

```
 @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()

                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()

                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        return http.build();
    }
```

Comment: `I am getting errors` and are we supposed to guess what errors? voted to close

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'antMatchers' in 'ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry'

Comment: Try requestMatchers

Comment: Edrel I am not getting requestMatchers also not available on http

Comment: No im not going to cancel my downvote. You have done poor research. Think about what the error message actually means. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

In spring framework 6 `.antMatchers` is not available anymore.
Instead, according to the [Spring security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html), you should do the following:

```
@Bean
protected SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()

            .authorizeHttpRequests( (auth) -> auth
                    .requestMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic().and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: and().httpBasic() How do I add this which is missing your code

Answer (score 0):

Since Spring Boot 3.0.0 (or spring framework 6),
`.antMatchers` for `AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry` is not available anymore.

Instead, use `.requestMatchers("/register")`

Example:

```java
http.authorizeHttpRequests( auth ->
    auth
        .requestMatchers(.....)
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    )
```

See Spring security documentation on *"Authorize HttpServletRequests with AuthorizationFilter"*:
[https://docs.spring.io/spring-security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html)